# jsGrid not displaying cell data after rows are retrieved

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jsgrid

I have a Controller that returns items:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAll(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var data = repository.GetAll(pageIndex, pageSize);

        return Ok(new
        {
            data,
            itemsCount = data.Count()
        });
    }
```

And the `jsGrid` setup is:

```
function setup() {
    $("#grid").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "auto",

        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        pageLoading: true,

        pageSize: 15,
        pageButtonCount: 5,

        controller: {
            loadData: function (filter) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/clients",
                    data: filter,
                    dataType: "JSON"
                });
            },
        },

        fields: [
            { name: "Id", type: "number", width: 50, visible: false },
            { name: "Date", type: "text", width: 100 },
            { name: "Client", type: "text", width: 200 },
            { name: "User", type: "text", width: 200 }
        ]
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    setup();
});
```

The table is populated with rows, however the cells are empty. Am I missing some mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Check your ajax result with Chrome Network tab. You can find that in the JSON object, the property name with lower case. So jsGrid can not map well.

Asp.Net Core return JSON object with lower-case name.

Answer (score 0):

As Li-gyu Gao say:
At first, see console tab of inspect element and make sure you don't have error in methid calling.
Then go to network tab of inspect element and find ypu request&response and check if the method gives respose and check your response with your model(in terms of field's names  & types) and if all of this sections correct, check your js function and try to drive in to multy mini function till find out your error in code for fix it.
I hope this answer help you man.